# Creating dash board in JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, reporting, dashboard, jasperserver

I am new to *JasperReports Server*. I have created two reports called summary and detail report. Summary report is a pie chart and detail report is a bar chart.

When I click on one slice in summary report the detail report is displaying accordingly. My requirement is have to create a dashboard with the above reports. In dashboard when I click on slice of pie chart the detail report should be updated. Can anybody explain how to achieve the above requirement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If someone answered your question please mark it as answered otherwise people are wasting their time visiting your questions.

Answer (score 3):

I gave a Jaspersoft presentation covering this type of thing. You can find it in the [webinar archive](http://www.jaspersoft.com/resources/webinars). It's called "Building Interactive Dashboards with Jaspersoft".

You you can go straight to the sample material on the [JasperForge.org forums](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=112&forumid=102&topicid=85369).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have gone thru the sample and achieved the drill down functionality.